# Ruby lib console.so load error and undifined symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a redmine ruby issue (see log below). As I absolutly know nothing about ruby, I'm asking for your guidence on how to solve this problem (redmine doesn't start anymore)

> /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   require': /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/io-console-0.5.0/lib/io/console.so:
>
> undefined symbol: RB_INTEGER_TYPE_P -
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/io-console-0.5.0/lib/io/console.so
>   (LoadError)
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require'
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/shell/basic.rb:2:in '
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require'
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require'
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/shell/color.rb:1:in '
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require'
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require'
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/shell.rb:17:in shell'
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/ui/shell.rb:15:in initialize'
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:13:in new'
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:13:in rescue in start'
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:17:in start'
>
> from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:30:in block in '
>
> from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in
>   with_friendly_errors'
>
> from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.0.2/exe/bundle:22:in '
>
> from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in load'
>
> from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in '

Comment: Computers are deterministic. They don't just suddenly decide to behave differently, just because they feel like it. If Redmine doesn't start anymore when it worked before, then someone made some change to the system. Without knowing what that change was, it is close to impossible to tell what the problem is.

Comment: You can try to reinstall `io-console` gem: `gem uninstall io-console` and `bundle install`.

Comment: I unistalled io-console then bundle install here is the result: Fetching https://github.com/a-ono/rich.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
sprockets-4.0.0 requires ruby version >= 2.5.0, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 2.3.3p222

Comment: Did you change anything since it's been working properly? If it worked previously, you must had had a compatible version of now incompatible gem in `Gemfile.lock` (or no gem at all).

Comment: Gemfile.lock is empty... I'm not the onlyone working on this server. Maybe an update?

Comment: An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.10.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.7'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: But you do have some sort of version control, right?

Comment: nope we doesn't have that for redmine